# Compactness of $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Thanks to Heine-Borel Theorem, we know that $[0,1]$ is compact in $\mathbb R$.
However, we I try to use the general topology definition of a compact set, I cannot "see" why it is true.

Here is what I have done :

Let $U_n = (\frac1n, 1-\frac1n)$ be a family of open sets of $\mathbb R$. This family is a cover of $[0,1]$ since $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}U_n = [0,1]$. Then by definition, it must exist a finite sub-family $(U_j)_{j\subset \mathbb N}$ with j finite that covers $[0,1]$.

I can't think of one.

Here is my conclusion :

- Either $U_n$ is not an open cover of $[0,1]$ and is an open cover of $(0,1)$.
- Either I didn't understand the definition.
- Either I didn't manage to see a finite subcover.

What do you think ?

Comment: Error in your infinite union. It doesn't capture the endpoints.

Comment: If you have a proof of hiene borel handy, you might want to follow it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither $0$ nor $1$ belong to any of the sets $U_n$. It is not a cover of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Can you show be a cover of $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: Sure. $(-1,2)$ is a cover of $[0,1]$.

Comment: I think op would still want to show that any cover has a finite sub cover.

Comment: I meant a family of opens $U_n$ such that $\cup_n U_n = [0,1]$

Comment: There is no such family since a union of open sets is again open.

Comment: @AlanSimonin what you want is a family of opens such that $\bigcup_n U_n \supseteq [0,1]$

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhh ok I see what I did wrong : Compactness means that if there exists a infinte cover of open sets, then it must exist a finite cover as well

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But the definition needs an equal sign : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_space

Comment: That's not it. It says that any open cover, no matter what, can be reduced to a finite subcover.

Comment: To explore compactness, use your family $U_n$, but instead think about them as a cover for $[1/10, 9/10]$ instead; any closed sub-interval of $(0, 1)$. Re "definition needing an equal sign", just intersect each set with the interval.

Comment: @AlanSimonin that's for a compact **space**.  If we're to consider $[0,1]$ as a space, then the sets $[0,a)$ and $(a,1]$ are open subsets.  If we want to show that $[0,1]$ is a compact **subset**, we want the condition that I describe.  The conditions are equivalent since a set in the space $[0,1]$ is open exactly when it can be written as $U \cap [0,1]$ for some open $U \subset \Bbb R$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I was lost but now I understand, thanks for your answer !